# Why are the two farthest points vertices of the Convex Hull?

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I read that in a 2D space, the two points farthest away must be in the convex hull (CH).

Intuitively, I can see why. If the two farthest points are not in the convex hull, then there must be a point that is outside the convex hull (contradiction). I know that a vertex of CH has two adjacent edges that converge at that point, which is of further distance from any other vertex or point within CH, than  the non-vertices beside it. What I mean is shown in the image below: a vertex (p) with two adjacent edges,

[image]

**Problem is**, I don't see how I can prove this more formally.  I am looking for a more concrete proof.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p,q$ be two points in your set of points. The point $p$ can be represented as some convex combination $\sum_i \alpha_i p_i$ of points on the convex hull. The triangle inequality gives
$$
\|p - q\| = \left\| \sum_i \alpha_i (p_i - q) \right\| \leq \sum_i \alpha_i \|p_i - q\| \leq \max_i \|p_i - q\|,
$$
where both inequalities used $\alpha_i \geq 0$ and the second also $\sum_i \alpha_i = 1$. We conclude that $p$ can be replaced by some point on the convex hull. Similarly, having replaced $p$ by a point on the convex hull, we can replace $q$ by a point on the convex hull.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the farthest point in *any* direction is on the convex hull. Actually, this applies much more generally. (I think probably for any closed and bounded set, but my real analysis is a little rusty.) Let $P$ be a simple closed polygon in the plane. Then $P$ partitions the plane into 3 regions: the interior of $I$ of $P$, the exterior $E$ of $P$, and the boundary $P$ itself. (Bonus reading: see the [the Jordan Curve Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem).)
Without 
loss of generality, we assume that the direction is the positive $x$ axis (just rotate your coordinate system).

Let $p$ be a point in $I \cup P$. If $p$ is not on the boundary $P$, then there exists another point $q$ in $I \cup P$ near $p$ with a larger $x$ coordinate, and so $p$ is not the point in $I \cup P$ with maximum $x$ coordinate. The contrapositive is that the point in $I \cup P$ with maximum $x$ coordinate is on the boundary $P$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late for the party, but anyway... Let $p$ and $q$ be two points, such that the distance $d$ between them is maximum over all the pairs of points in the given point set. All the *other* points must be inside the **intersection of two disks** with radius $d$ - one disk with center in the point $p$ and another disk with center in the point $q$. This intersection looks like a *curvilinear rhombus* with diagonal $(p, q)$ and circular sides with radius $d$.
[image: rhombus]
Now we'll use the observation from the @Joe answer - *the farthest point in any direction belongs to the convex hull*. In our case this direction is defined by the line, passing through points $p$ and $q$, and these two points are obviously farthest along this direction.